# AWS China Region Console Has Bad S3 Assets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, great-firewall-of-china

Looking at the below screenshot, I first thought maybe it's a Chrome on Linux problem.  So I booted the windows partition and tried both FireFox and Chrome.

[image]

The next thing I thought is maybe because of the Great Firewall, there's some serious latency to where I am in Boston.  However a colleague in Ohio is able to connect just fine.

I even booted a Linux Mint Live USB and saw the same thing on that FireFox.

Any thoughts as to what's happening here?

Comment: I have found that the Chinese firewall can vary moment to moment and, in general, is difficult to predict (probably by design).  We ended up having to VPN into a server in China to test.

Comment: I also agree with @stdunbar

Comment: That's what my colleague also says.  It's my first day on the China team

Answer (score 1):

The could be essentially anything in the path from your computer to the destination.  The links are correct and the site appears to be working normally.  You could try troubleshooting with tools like `traceroute` to verify it's not an issue with your network, firewall, or ISP, but that tool can give misleading results if you don't have a baseline to compare against.

The certificate message is unrelated; AWS reportedly has a fix underway that will resolve that warning.